# In spark, are there cases where GroupByKey is preferred to ReduceByKey?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

It's a well known optimization to replace GroupByKey with ReduceByKey, since the latter reduces shuffling. I was wondering if there are reverse cases in which code with GroupByKey is faster than with ReduceByKey.

Comment: I think the only case would be when datasize is really small.

Comment: I don't think it can be faster, but depending on the output you want `reduceByKey` will not always work.